# "Obtaining IP" problem while connecting to WiFi home network on Jelly Bean 4.1.2

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s, samsung-galaxy-s-duos

I have recently brought a new Samsung mobile with android jelly bean. Till now it was working fine but after the update it is unable to connect to WiFi network and getting stuck at `Obtaining IP`.

How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this happens when the device is set back to **default manufacturing date**.

Reset the  **date** to **current date** and everything will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check if you entered the WIFI password correctly.